# permission denied when trying to remove folders with files in php

Tags: php, file-permissions

I have a php script that, creates a folder first and puts pictures in it, but the real problem is, I cannot delete folder and files in it, I give the permission 755 to that folder when files created, the problem is, when I try to delete it with unlink or system("rm -rf"), I get the error of permission denied. I tried to change permissions of files and folders by using chmod and umask, but it did not work too.

Is there something that I can give php permissions ? or any other solutions,

--- I tried every possible script that can be found on stackoverflow and other websites, so there is nothing wrong with my script. Thank you

Comment: Apache should have permission on the folder. Try `chown -R` to your apache user

Comment: Does your script work when you chmod to 777?